# two different urls in same state with Angular JS $stateProvider

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I am using Angular-ui-router with Angular Js, and I have a requirement that I want to use the same state for two patterns of URLS 
e.g

/about 
and
/about/mission-vision

I want both the urls to use same state with stateProvider , is there a way to achieve that ?

Bellow is my code for state

```
$stateProvider.state('spages.page', {
                url: ':slug',
                views : {
                  ...
                },
                resolve:{
                  ...  
                }
            });
```

For next url

```
$stateProvider.state('spages.page', {
                    url: ':parentslug/:slug',
                    views : {
                      ...
                    },
                    resolve:{
                      ...  
                    }
                });
```

I would like to combine both the states.

Comment: I don't think it is possible, maybe i'm wrong :)

Comment: No, but you could redirect it

Comment: It's not possible, because you can navige by set $state, if you have two url's on the same $state router don't know which one should use. How do you imagine result of `$state.go('spages.page')` ?

Comment: @szapio yeah thats what I thought too, but I thought there must be a way to put them together. Anyways, thanks all